# Identifiying varying XPATHs

Tags: python, html, xpath

I am trying to scrape web data in iterative loops. Every loop has to deal with a different part of the website.

The URL I am scraping is: https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/freiburg-dortmund-WAyMx9XS/?r=4#over-under;2;2.50;0

As can be seen there are multiple Over/Under sections, that I am looping through.

The items I am interested in have an XPATH like this:

```
//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]
```

Another element in a different category but of the same type:

```
//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[10]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]
```

And another element of the same category but different type:

```
//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[10]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div
```

As can be seen, the structure remains the same, it is just the div/tr that changes.

How can I account for this in my Python code?

Currently I am running this:

```
for x in range(1,28):
        for j in range(1,15): 
            Book = self.ffi('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[{}]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[1]/div/a[2]'.format(x,j))
```

As you can see I am looping every possible DIV/TR combination, however this creates many unncecessary loops..

Is there a way to do this with a contains/follows xpath?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the url and the exact expected output.

Comment: @JackFleeting Done!
Hope it helps.

Comment: It does help but not completely. You still haven't shown your exact expected output. Also, the data on this site is dynamically loaded using javascript; did you account for that?

Comment: @JackFleeting the expected output would be for each iteration the information Bookkeeper, Over and Under. What do you mean by "dynamically loaded"? I accounted for it in so far, that I am opening in each iteration the URL containing th appropriate Over/Under data

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do that that uses relative path. You can find all rows of the `odds-data-table` using:

```py
    odds_data_table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="table-container" and not(contains(@style,"display: none;"))]')
```

Then, interact over each row, and also click in the option "Click to show X more bookmarkers":

```py
for table in odds_data_table:
    table.click()
    table.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[./strong[contains(text(),"Click to show")]]').click()
```

This will open all available bookmakers, and you can get all of them in one shot using, for example:

```py
urls = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="name"]') if elem.text]
```

You can also do that inside each loop interaction, if you need to know on which row of the odd data table you are.